# Number of elements of order 2 in cyclic group of even order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Q1 The Number of elements of order $2$ in a cyclic group of even order is

1. 1
2. 2
3. 4
4. 8

I know a group of even order must have an element of order 2.

Q2. A finitely generated subgroup of $G$ of additive group $\mathbb Q$ satisfies the condition

1. $G$ is isomorphic to $Q$

2.$G$ is cyclic.

3.$G$ is finite.

Comment: Hint: For Q1, what does it mean for the group to be cyclic? For Q2, is $\mathbb{Q}$ finitely generated?

Comment: @JustinBenfield if a group is cyclic then it has elements which generate the whole group. and $\mathbb Q$ is not finitely generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1 You need to prove (or to get convinced that):

Claim: A finite cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ has one unique subgroup of order $\;q\;$ for each and every divisor $\;q\;$ of $\;n\;$

Q2 Try to do it first with two generators and prove it is cyclic. Now use an easy inductive argument to show any finitely generated subgroup of the rationals is cyclic.

Comment: so cyclic group $G$ will have one subgroup of order 2 hence number of elements of order 2 is 1. Am I right?

Comment: @GautamSinglaThat's right.

Comment: Given any two elements $a, b\in Q$ then we can find $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a=pr$ $b=qr$ so we can say group generated by $a,b$ is subgroup of group generated by $r$. and because subgroup of cyclic group is cyclic so finitely generated subgroup of rationals is cyclic.